# Android app: Multiple DND (Do Not Disturb) rules for different schedules

Tags: scheduling, android-app

Is there any recommendation for an Android app for my following requirements?

I am looking to have two DND (Do Not Disturb) schedules with two different rules as follows:

> 1. From 12:00 AM till 7:00 am - No sound for any notification from any application, but calls are allowed for everybody.
> 2. From 7:00 AM till I stop - No sound, no calls are allowed except for the calls from Favorites contacts.

The second one I already have successfully running on my phone, but I find no way to have both the schedules running on one phone.

Android gives option to define only one set of DND rules and all the schedules will follow the same rules set.

I am looking for something where I can have two different rule sets for two schedules.

As far as I can see and search, it is not possible with Android default.

Is there any app which can allow me to do this specific thing? Gratis or paid app will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another thing easily doable with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (not free, but
definitely worth the money):

- set up **Time** state profile based on your chosen hours, with entry task that enables DND and exit task that disables it
- the "till I stop" condition is achievable in many different ways, e.g. with **Button Widget Clicked** (UI) event. Or you can just turn it off like you'd normally do.
- use **Do Not Disturb** action in tasks to toggle that